# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested even after using moveToFirst()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I am experimenting with SQLite databases in Android and I have a simple but really annoying issue. I get the following exception while runnign my code:

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

As you can see the result is not empty (size is 1) and I also call the result.moveToFirst() method to postion the cursor correctly but the problem still remains. I also tried using the result.moveToPosition(0) method before the return statement with no success.

The following method is included in my DatabaseHelper class and it throws the exception on the line with the return statement.

```
public boolean authenticateUser(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT PASSWORD FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE USERNAME = '" + username + "'", null);
    //no such username in the database
    if (!result.moveToFirst()) return false;
    return result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD")).equals(password);
}
```

I have one table in the database which was created with the following commands included in the onCreate method of the DatabaseHelper class:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS (USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, personID INTEGER)");   

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS VALUES('user1', 'user1', 1)");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS VALUES('user2', 'user2', 2)");
```

I verified that the database got created correctly and the data was inserted.

In my MainActivity I have a DatabaseHelper myDB variable.

```
myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

And at a certain point I call the method

```
myDB.authenticateUser("user1", "user1");
```

Comment: i think getColumnIndex() is case sensitive. check the name of the column password in the database. is in UPPER CASE or LOWER CASE ?

Comment: This is the creation string for the ACCOUNTS table, everything is written with capital letters: CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS (USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, personID INTEGER)

Comment: The full call stack of the exception would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of having

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS (USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, personID INTEGER)");
```

I used

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS (USERNAME TEXT, pwd TEXT, personID INTEGER)");
```

(notice the lower case column name for password)

and then

`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT pwd FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE USERNAME = '" + username + "'", null);
        //no such username in the database
        if (result == null || !result.moveToFirst()) return false;
        return result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("pwd")).equals(password);`

And everything seemed to work just fine. Then I thought 'hey, what the heck, this shouldn't happen' so I reverted everything to how it was before.

Lo and behold, everything worked just fine again. Are you sure you're not .. not deleting the database before trying stuff out again? You should just uninstall the app and then re-run it from the IDE or whatever you are using if you make db changes like column names and stuff (well at least in case you don't already have tons of data)

Comment: Uninstalling the app and reinstalling the new version did the trick. Thank you!